# Thermal radiation / First law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

We know that thermal radiation is one of the ways energy can be transferred from one object to another.
And we know, objects at any temperature emit electromagnetic radiation.

So does that mean molecules and atoms are constantly losing energy?
And why isn't this considered in the first law of thermodynamics?
How can we even calculate the amount of thermal energy converted into electromagnetic energy (radiation).

Comment: Objects are also always absorbing energy from the surroundings. The First Law contains a term Q representing net heat transfer, including radiative transfer. Please consider clarifying your specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be many questions in this post. We encourage our users to ask only one question. Anyway here are some answers:

> We know that thermal radiation is one of the ways energy can be transferred from one object to another. And we know, objects at any temperature emit electromagnetic radiation. So does that mean molecules and atoms are constantly losing energy?

Sure the molecules are losing energy, but also gaining energy from their surroundings. If everything is at the same temperature, there is not net flow (in/out) of energy.

> And why isn't this considered in the first law of thermodynamics?

For most problems, the contribution due to radiation can be neglected/ignored (no net flux). If not, you have to add the energy carried by the electromagnetic fields  in your conservation equation.

> How can we even calculate the amount of thermal energy converted into electromagnetic energy (radiation).

For a first approximation on how thermal radiation is calculated for a solid body, look for [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). A good estimation for the heat emitted by a body at a certain temperature is given by [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).

Comment: Thank you so much, and forgive me for asking so many questions at once